# .NET Core 2 Access Configuration without DI

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a EF entity object that I have a non-mapped property that I would like to access the appsettings.json from that property but cant seem to find a good way to do it.

What is the best way to have a non controller class access configuration settings

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you please include source code and show what is not working in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a EF entity object that I have a non-mapped property that I would like to access the appsettings.json from that property but cant seem to find a good way to do it.

When things are overly difficult, it's usually a sign that you're proceeding down the wrong path. Here, that's definitely the case. Your entity classes should be nothing more that DTOs. It is not the place for logic. Having a non-mapped property that needs access to the configuration *screams* logic.

A good way to tell when you should or should not have logic in a class, is whether it's capable of forgoing a parameterless constructor. In the case of something like an entity class, it *must* have a parameterless constructor, which means it's completely incapable of being dependency-injected. If it can't be dependency-injected, it generally should not have any logic.

Long and short, move the logic you think you need in that property somewhere else: a view model, helper class, etc. - some place you can inject the configuration into.